# SQL Join vs Where

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say we have following two tables:

> A (id, name, type)
>
> B (id, A_id, data)

Hence from above

> A has_many B (foreign_key : A_id)

Now can we say following that

```
if B is not indexed on A_id then B INNER JOIN A will be slow ?
```

Also lets assume that we know that

```
SELECT * FROM B WHERE B.A_id = 100
```

takes **x seconds**.

Can we make any conclusion on how much time `INNER-JOIN` will take based on this ?

Comment: Firstly, A has many B (not the other way around). Secondly, you should have indexes on all foreign keys. This is so common and advisable that Mysql for example creates one for you automatically.

Comment: So not having an index on foreign key will always slow down the join ?

Comment: Joining without an index (foreign key or otherwise) will always perform better with an index, unless the number of rows in the parent table is small (say less than 100), in which case the performance will likely be the same because often using indexes is slower than simply reading the entire table if it fits on a couple of IO pages.

Comment: So, when should we create an index on foreign key, as based on your comments, sometimes indexes on foreign key will slow down the join process ?

Comment: that question was already answered.

Comment: where ? can you please mention it again ?

Comment: Always create an index. The database optimizer will figure out if its worth using it. It will never be slower having an index. Just do it. Everyone else does.

Comment: Well, indices make `INSERT`/`UPDATE`/`DELETE` operations slower (that is, _everything else_), so it's a balancing act.  Which is why large retailers often have 2 dbs - one for the incoming daily transactions (lots of `INSERT`s), and one for marketing analysis (lots of `SELECT`s).  But for most common consumer/small business applications you're not likely to get close to the necessary volume where it's a problem.  Instead, bad schema design is more likely to trip you up or slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the exact timings might depend on the DBMS being used, but it'll probably be negligible.

In theory they should have a very similar performance, exact timing would be difficult to discern due to the many uncertainties involved: number of processes running, etc.

If you're using oracle you could try [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm) if you're using oracle, other DBMS have similar systems.

The execution plan for a join would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN A ON A.id = B.id;

-- 0 select statement
-- 1 hash join (access("A"."ID"="B"."ID"))
-- 2 table access full A
-- 3 table access full B
```

The execution plan for a where would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM A, B
WHERE A.id = B.id;

-- 0 select statement
-- 1 hash join (access("A"."ID"="B"."ID"))
-- 2 table access full A
-- 3 table access full B
```

They should have a very similar performance, `JOIN` is an ANSI standard, it is easy to read and can easily be changed to `OUTER JOIN`/`LEFT JOIN`/`RIGHT JOIN`, I suggest you should always use a `JOIN` over a `WHERE`

Comment: and what about indexing strategy ? Should we always index the keys on which we will be joining ? @Bohemian mentioned it could sometimes make joining slow ?

Comment: It could go either way, check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg06idx.htm). In terms of basic performance the where and join are the same. Do you really need your data look ups to be faster? Are you actually storing enough data to cause a noticeable slow down? If you really are keep these two tips in mind: take only the collumns you need (avoid `SELECT *`) and consider using temp tables to handle hot-spots in your data.

Comment: If you couldn't be bothered to read all that, then just create an index, the DBMS will optimise for you.